# Make numbered list from array

Tags: php

Here is what im using for test purposes to simplify what im asking for. What im trying to achieve is:

> 1. Firstnameinarray, 2. Secondnameinarray, 3. Thirdnameinarray

Right now I am getting this:

> Firstnameinarray, Secondnameinarray, Thirdnameinarray

this is the code:

```
$list = file("pready.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $num = 0;

        $listn = implode(", ", $list );
        $get = explode(",", $listn);

        echo "$listn";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "$get[0]"; //this is for my testing of another part of the script
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you show what is inside of your _pready.txt_ ? Just a sample data will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. I'm not aware of a native function that will do exactly what you want, so this is kind of a roundabout way to do it.

```
$list = file("pready.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$resultString = "";

foreach($list as $index => $entry)
{
    $resultString .= $index . ". " . $entry . ", ";
}

$resultString = substr($resultString, 0 , -2);

echo $resultString;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! I was looking at this issue to deep into perspective I've spent hours in the wrong places!

Answer (score 0):

If you really love implode and want to keep it as an array until the end, you can array_walk with a join through it:

```
array_walk($list, function($v, $k) { return $k + 1 . ". $v"; });
$res = implode(', ', $list));
```

Comment: [array_walk()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) returns a boolean, so you can't use it like that.

Comment: Ah right - PHP's unfortunately inconsistent with its array function syntax, and the above is assuming array_map()-like behaviour. array_walk() is the one that passes its key into the callback, but returns a boolean not the array. Fixed answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Try going through `$listn` and building and ordered list.

```
$list = file("pready.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$num = 0;

$listn = implode(", ", $list );
$get = explode(",", $listn);

if(!empty($listn)) {
  echo "<ol>";
  foreach($listn as $key => $value) {
    echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
  }
  echo "</ol>";
}

echo "<br />";
echo "$get[0]"; //this is for my testing of another part of the script
```